# Im trying to create a login class but my ajax json parsing isn't getting a correct response

Tags: php, class

Im trying to use ajax to submit a form and return type either Business or Admin but I'm getting:

JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

result= JSON.parse(r);

```
<input type="text" id="signinemail" placeholder="Email" name="signinemail">

<input type="password" id="signinpassword" placeholder="Password"
name="signinpassword">

<script>

  $(function() { 

    $("#signinsubmit").click(function() {

      var username = $("#signinemail").val();

      $.post("signin.php",
      {

        signinusername: username, signinpassword: $("#signinpassword").val() 
      }     )

       .done( function(r)
      {

        result= JSON.parse(r);  

      if(result["user_type"]=="Business") 

      {

          window.location="profile.php";
      }

      else if(result["user_type"]=="Admin") 

      {

          window.location="requestpage.php";

      }

      });

      });

      });

</script>
```

This is the class that trying to login in with. It firsts takes the post gives it to the authenticate function then returns the result of the connection to the log in function that encodes it

```
<?php

/**
* Logs the User into Website
*/
class Login
{

    private $connection;
    private $result_array = array();
    private $user_type;
    private $id;
    public $username;
    private $password;
    public $loggedIn;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->username = $_POST['signinemail'];
        $this->password = $_POST['signinpassword'];
        $this->connection = new mysqli('WolfeboroC.db.10688096.hostedresource.com', 'WolfeboroC', 'Brewster#1', 'WolfeboroC');
        $this->authenticate();
        $this->logIn($this->authenticate);
    }

    private function authenticate()
    {

        $query = "SELECT recid, Admin FROM users 
                  WHERE User = '".$this->$username."' 
                  AND password='".$this->$password."' 
                  AND (verified='y' OR admin = 'y') 
                  LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = mysqli_master_query($this->connection, $query);

        $this->result_array = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt);

        return !empty($this->result_array);

    }


private function logIn()
{

    if($result_array->num_rows > 0) 
    {

        if($result_array['Admin']=='y') 
        {

            $this->user_type = "Admin";
            $this->admin($this->result_array);
            $this->loggedIn = true;
        }

        else 
        {

            $this->user_type = "Business";
            $this->business($this->result_array);
            $this->loggedIn = true;
        }

        echo json_encode($this->user_type['user_type']);
    }

}

}

?>
```

Comment: So what is sent from server to client? First step: wither dump on server side or use the debugging console inside your clilent (browser).

Comment: the type either Business or Admin

Comment: That is not an answer. I asked for what is actually sent from server to client. Sent in a literal way. Visualize the payload.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean ajax as a done function that gets the response which is the echo json_encode()

Comment: instead of result["user_type"] , use =>result.user_type ??

Comment: @user876345 are you asking what this is?

Comment: Since ajax complains that the payload sent is not valid JSON data it _might_ make sense to look at that data directly instead of _guessing_ what might be sent. That is all I meant.

Comment: i tried to do an alert of the json but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

echo json_encode($this->user_type['user_type']); is not correct. Your user_type is not an array so don't try to access it like this. You either do a echo $this->user_type and use the result as a string in javascript OR put the value in an array and then json_encode it like this:

```
echo json_encode(array('user_type' => $this->user_type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using to get json response as,

```
result.user_type
```

instead of

```
result["user_type"]
```

In login() function: json synatx should be

```
echo json_encode(array('user_type' => $this->user_type));
```

instead of,

```
 echo json_encode($this->user_type['user_type']);
```

Comment: Can you post your json response here

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
 

result= JSON.parse(r);

Comment: Can you please post json response?

Comment: when i try to do a alert of the json data i get the unexpected data error

Comment: get the  signin.php output response from browser use firefox net tool to find the response?

Comment: i can't find net tool